# Exclude *.java source files from WAR package

Tags: java, maven, war

I have a problem with filtering my *.java files from resulting WAR package.
I'm using maven 3.0.3. My pom.xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<parent>
    <groupId>com.my</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>1.00</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.my.app</groupId>
<artifactId>app</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>My Webapp</name>

<build>
    <finalName>My</finalName>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>

        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
....
```

and then I'm asembling my WAR with `mvn clean package`. 
After that I can see all my *.java files inside my WAR. Am I having wrong config or\and am I executing wrong maven plugins?

P.S. I've also tried to use the following plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <warSourceExcludes>**/*.java</warSourceExcludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

with `mvn war:war` but with no success.

Comment: Why are you filtering src/main/java and why have you defined it as resource?

Comment: Well :) the first results about excluding files from WAR  are about using <resource> directive. I (and also the guy who wrote this config years ago before me) thought, why can't we use it to filter *.java files out from WAR? And maybe it worked that way before. But now, looks like it's bad idea :)

Comment: Hm..you didn't really answered my question: Why do you use filtering for Java files? Usually you don't need to filter java source files, cause they are compiled and that's it. So no need to do that which results in no need for excluding them from the war.

Comment: Ermm.. :) i'm sorry if i've answered not clearly enough. The guy who wrote this config thought that filtering prevents *.java files from being copied to WAR and i have followed this assumption. I mean, we have completelly missunderstood the meaning of this option. But indeed now, when i've removed this entire <resource> section - i have no *.java files in my WAR. So that was the problem :) And that is solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I could answer your WAR-related question, but I'm going AWOL for the weekend as of.. now!

Answer (score 1):

With @khmarbaise 's help i have found the cause of a problem. In my case i just removed the "<resource>" section for "src/main/java" folder.

Answer (score 0):

Don't Use `<warSourceExcludes>`, try as like below

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.2.0</version>
<configuration>
<packagingExcludes>
    WEB-INF/**/*.java
</packagingExcludes>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```